# Seit wann ist ein Dreier flott?

Tags: etymology

Der Duden kennt die Bestandteile »Dreier« und »flott« u. a. als:

> Dreier: (salopp) Geschlechtsverkehr zu dritt
>   flott: leichtlebig, lebenslustig und unbeschwert

Die beiden Bestandteile sind also unmissverständlich.
Als stehende Wendung ist »flotter Dreier« überraschend, weil hier ein (zu unterschiedlicher Zeit unterschiedlich stark) tabuisiertes Phänomen einen komischen Namen bekommt.

Wikipedia nennt noch andere Beispiele für »[flotter Dreier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flotter_Dreier)« genannte Dinge oder Ereignisse.
Die stammen aber alle aus der jüngeren Vergangenheit.

Seit wann wird Sex zu dritt als »flotter Dreier« bezeichnet, und gibt es eine anerkannte Erstverwendung?
Oder tritt in Musik, Literatur etc. ein »flotter Dreier« in anderer Bedeutung auf, von dem der Ausdruck abgeleitet sein könnte, so wie die sprichwörtlichen Pappenheimer?

Comment: "Dreier" gab es früher in rauhen Mengen, von der Briefmarke über Gewichte und Gespanne bis zu Münzen (Naheliegend, wenn man bedenkt, das früher das Zwölfer-System verbreiteter war als das Zehnersystem). Um zu signalisieren, dass man "was anderes meinte", musste man eben "was dranhängen"...

Comment: @tofro: Was meinst Du mit früher, die 70er, die 20er, das Mittelalter, urindogermanisch?

Comment: Dieses "früher" würde ich im 18. und 19. Jhd. verorten, wobei der Beginn aber auch in noch fernerer Vergangenheit liegen könnte.

Comment: Ich hätte da eher die 1950er Jahre als Ursprungszeitraum im Visier... oder allenfalls die 1960er.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Den ersten sexuell konnotierten flotten Dreier finde ich in [einem Artikel aus dem Spiegel, vom **8. März 1982**](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-14333989.html):

> Da sollten dem US-Präsidenten Richard Nixon durch einen Einflußagenten "deutsche Ansichten" beigebracht werden (Aktion "Monica II"), ein andermal ging's um einen **flotten Dreier** im Bett einer masochistischen Agentin ("Aktion Hornisse").

Der Google Ngram Viewer zeigt mir, dass er auch aus dem Jahr 1972 ein Druckwerk findet, in dem die Wortfolge »flotten Dreier« vorkommt, allerdings zeigt der Viewer die Fundstelle nicht an. In einer separaten Büchersuche konnte ich aus diesem Zeitraum nur »die **Flotten dreier** Nationen« und ähnliche Formulierungen finden, die *user unknown* bereits in seiner Antwort erwähnt hat, und die nichts mit dem gesuchten Begriff zu tun haben.

Überhaupt ist die Recherche im Internet schwierig, weil alle Seiten, die ein Datum aus den 1970er- und 80er-Jahren tragen, erst viel später erstellt wurden und daher kaum eine dieser Seiten wirklich authentisch ist. So finde ich z.B. eine Schallplattenkritik zu einer Platte der Blue Öyster Band, die mit »6. April 1974« datiert ist, und in der von den drei ersten Alben der Band als »flotten Dreier« gesprochen wird, aber weiter unten in demselben Text wird dann die Band *Metallica* erwähnt, die jedoch erst 1981 gegründet wurde, was bedeutet, dass die Kritik nicht wirklich 1974 erschienen sein kann.

Interessanterweise findet auch viele Vintage-Pornos aus dem 1970er- und 80er-Jahren (das ist noch nicht das Interessante), aber keiner davon trägt die Bezeichnung »flotter Dreier« im Namen (das hingegen ist interessant), sondern dieser Begriff wird immer nur in Kommentaren und Beschreibungen verwendet, die erst Jahrzehnte später verfasst wurden.

Der einzige Treffer, den ich wirklich für authentisch halte, ist der eingangs zitierte Spiegel-Artikel aus dem Jahr 1982.

**Daher kann ich behaupten:**

Sex zu dritt wurde bereits zu Beginn der 1980er-Jahre als »flotter Dreier« bezeichnet (siehe Spiegel-Zitat). Allerdings war damals die Kombination »flott + Dreier« noch so wenig gebräuchlich, dass sie nicht einmal in Titeln von Pornofilmen verwendet wurde.

Was allerdings dazu geführt hat, dass diese Wendung danach (vor allem ab Mitte der 1990er-Jahre) gängig wurde, lässt sich nur schwer mit Gewissheit feststellen. Auch eine »anerkannte Erstverwendung« wird sich nur schwer finden lassen (obwohl ich das erwähnte Spiegel-Zitat für einen chancenreichen Kandidaten halte).

Comment: "noch so wenig gebräuchlich, dass sie nicht einmal in Titeln von Pornofilmen verwendet wurde" - wird sie das denn heute? Falls die Vermutung aus [tofros Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46081/seit-wann-ist-ein-dreier-flott#comment111343_46081) zutrifft, dürfte durch den Kontext ja meist schon klar sein, worum es geht, wodurch die Abgrenzung gegenüber nichtsexuellen "Dreiern" eigentlich nicht mehr nötig wäre (oder sogar ein etwaiges Wortspiel, wie es in Filmtiteln mitunter vorkommt, stören könnte).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Deine Frage: »"noch so wenig gebräuchlich, dass sie nicht einmal in Titeln von Pornofilmen verwendet wurde" - wird sie das denn heute?« - Meine Antwort: Wenn ich z.B. auf xhamster nach »flotter Dreier« suche, behauptet die Suchmaschine dieser Seite, 112.400 Videos gefunden zu haben, in denen dieser Begriff vorkommt, und es werden auch gleich mehr als zwei Dutzend konkrete Videos angezeigt, die diesen Begriff im Titel enthalten. Deine Frage, ob die Kombination »flott + Dreier« heute in Titeln von Pornofilmen verwendet wird, lässt sich also mit einem sehr klaren *»JA«* beantworten.

Answer (score 2):

Für "flotter Dreier" finde ich mit Hilfe von [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flotter%20Dreier%2Cflotten%20Dreier&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflotten%20Dreier%3B%2Cc0) erstmalig 1978 drei Treffer, als da sind:

> "Ein Mädchen ist fast so gut wie ein Junge": Sexismus in der Erziehung
>   Dagmar Schultz - 1978 - ‎Das bißchen,
>   was da abgelaufen ist, lief meist nur über einen Typen, auf den Frau
>   sich jederzeit zurückziehen konnte (flotter Dreier). Einige stehen Sex
>   mit Frauen genauso widerstrebend gegenüber wie vor der Zeit der
>   Frauengruppe, bzw.
>
> Der RALF-Report: d. Sexualverhalten d. Dt. : zsfassende Darst. d. ...
>   Klaus Eichner, ‎Werner Habermehl - 1978 - ‎
>   Mit mehreren zusammen, also Gruppensex. Angestellte, 21-30 J., vh., o K., ev.: Gruppensex, flotter Dreier, gleichgeschlechtliche Beziehungen. Hausfrau, 21-30 J., vh., 2 K., ev.: Vielleicht mal mit kultivierten Leuten ein bißchen Gruppensex.
>
> Das Pult - Ausgaben 48-54 - Seite 196
>   1978 - Alleinsein, Zweierbeziehung, flotter Dreier und Wohngemeinschaft wird es nebeneinander geben, die Kräfte der einzelnen Pressuregroups werden einander mühselig die Waage halten.

Ein älterer Fund ist ein Fehlfund der Art "die Flotten dreier Seemächte".

Für "flotten Dreier" finde ich:

> Gelandewagen 1: Berlin - Band 1 - Seite 110
>   Wolfgang Storch - **1979** - ‎... alles - also hinterher ist's bestimmt ganz witzig. sucht etwas Fred, du Arsch. sucht Mit zwei dicken, verkommenen Buben, ohne Licht, zwischen Tür und Angel im Stehen, einen flotten Dreier. findet etwas Eßbares Mehlklumpen- Aldi-Gebäck.

Dabei ist zu bedenken, dass Google-NGram wohl nur Bücher und Zeitschriften durchsucht. Gesprochene Sprache oder private Notizen, Briefe, Tagebücher werden also nicht erfasst. Mit Fraktur tut sich NGram auch notorisch schwer.

Answer (score 0):

"Flotter Dreier" ist tatsächlich nur und ausschliesslich die sexuelle Dreierbeziehung, mit Betonung auf das Unbeschwerte. Es ist informelle Sprache, "Dreier" ist eine Abkürzung für "Dreierbeziehung".
Die anderen in der Wikipedia genannten Bedeutungen sind allesamt (nicht ernstgemeinte) Unterstellungen einer sexuellen Komponente.

Comment: Das beantwortet noch nicht die Frage nach dem "seit wann". Kannst Di das eventuell ergänzen?

Comment: Ah, das weiss ich leider nicht. Sorry, Frage falsch verstanden.